# How to optimize setState in async fn？

Tags: reactjs

Due to multiple setstates do not merge execute in asynchronous functions.How to optimize the performance of setState by calling setState multiple times in an asynchronous function？

```
        requestApi.query({
            data: {
                querycondition,
                oid
            },
            success: (data) => { //it's a async success callback with ajax

                //The following three component apis call setState internally so that it is rendered three times
                this.fillTable(data.table.rows); 
                this.showSuccessToast();
                this.openFitstRowModal();
            }
        })
```

```
 query: (opt) => {
        ajax({
            url: '/nccloud/ssctp/sscbd/SSCTaskHandleQueryAction.do',
            data: opt.data,
            loading: opt.loading,
            success: (data) => {
                opt.success(data.data)
            }
        })
    }
```

The following three functions come from different components

```
    fillTalbe(rows) {
        //ignore others code
        this.setState({
            rows
        })
    }

    showSuccessToast() {
        this.setState({
            showSuccessToast: true
        })
    }

    openFitstRowModal() {
        this.setState({
            openFirstRowModal: true
        })
    }
```

Comment: SetState is called in the components API

Comment: Can you show your code and add more details to your post

Comment: Updating react state is already asynchronous, if none of the updates depend on previous state then just enqueue them. If you have subsequent logic that *depends* on previous computed values (that may be an enqueued state update) you'll need to hold on to them and use the value stored in function scope, *then* enqueue a state update with the final value.

Comment: SetState is executed sync in async functions. So I want to know what is the optimal way for setState to sync in a particular situation?

Comment: The success callback isn't an async function, and presumably any state updates from any of those three functions should be enqueued during the same render cycle. Do any of those three functions do anything asynchronously? Please include all relevant code.

Comment: How should be optimized assuming that success is an async function？

Comment: Nothing to assume. Success ***isn't*** an async function.

Comment: If success is sync function ,why render function be called three times?

Comment: The render function can be called almost any time, for any reason, by the react framework. Please review this [lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/). Notice the `render` function is in the render phase, not the commit phase, react is likely testing each state update in order to compute a diff to determine what *actually* needs to be committed and flushed to the DOM. How are you determining multiple renders are occurring? Is there a performance issue? Are you just trying to pre-optimize?